# Android: EditText setError covers up standard AlertDialog buttons

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I have a standard (not custom, no layout) `AlertDialog` with literally just an `EditText` as its view and two buttons (OK and cancel.)

When there's a problem with the input, I show an error message that ends up being three lines of text, which occludes the OK and cancel buttons.  The error text does disappear once the user types something, but I'd sure like the cancel button to be visible.

Is there any (easy) way of changing the placement of the error text?

Comment: I also hit this problem.  Sounds like a bug in the framework.  The EditText code should be smarter about rendering the popup.  I filed Android issue 30602: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=30602

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, not without some customization.  The internal `PopupWindow`  managed for the error display is called with `showAsDropDown()`, which let's Android decide where to display the view in relation to it's anchor (the error icon, in this case) and it will always be below the view unless there is not enough window space.  You would have to create (albeit fairly simple) subclass of EditText that displays the internal `PopupWindow` using `showAtLocation()` instead.

Here's the link to the [TextView source](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java&q=package%3aandroid.git.kernel.org%20file%3aandroid/widget/TextView.java&l=1) to hopefully help out if you want to try that.  The `setError()` and `showError()` methods are what you would be after overriding.

HTH